# Laravel Eloquent | change database name within the same connection

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Im wondering is it possible to change database name **within the same connection**?

The reason is that Im working on a report which needs to loop through all of the databases (more than 100) within the same connection (host, user, pass).

Currently I just manually add the database name before each table name in query. Like:

`` "SELECT * FROM `database_a`.`users` WHERE ..."; ``

I made some searches on Google with "change database name" or "switch database..." but most of them are about creating different connections array in `config/database.php` but thats not my case (with more than 100 databases)

Thanks

Comment: What kind of database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only changing the database name, create an array with all your databases names. Then using query builder you can do in a loop

```
DB::table($databasesArray[0].'.table_name')->where(...)
```

I think this would put you in the right track.
E.g:

```
$databases = ['db1','db2'];

foreach($databases as $db) {
    $users [] = DB::table($db.'.users')->where('status', 'active')->get();
}
// $users = all users from all Databases
```

Comment: Yeah thats what im doing, however I dont think thats good approach because I have to manually build the database name array. Thanks anw

Answer (score 4):

What about defining database in table selection ?

```
class Book extends Model {

    protected $table = 'database1.books'

}

class Book2 extends Model {

    protected $table = 'database2.books'

}
```

Comment: Im using raw query :((

Comment: this answer solved my problem thanks